# UIWebView reloading baseUrl when setting contents from NSURLConnectionDataDelegate

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to create an single `UIWebView`-based application. Its main purpose is to provide authentication to a few websites using NTLM or Basic authentication, without the user having to input the username/password for every website when he/she changes his password (the websites share the user/password database).

In order to do that, I'm "overriding" the loading of page data for the `UIWebView`, so that I can intercept the HTTP response codes and ask the user for a password every time I detect a `401 Unauthorized` response.

I've set up a `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` to handle the requests as such:

```
@interface LPURLConnectionDelegate : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
{
    UIWebView* _webView;
    NSMutableURLRequest* _request;
    NSURLConnection* _connection;
    NSString* _encoding;
    NSString* _mimeType;
    NSMutableData* _data;
}

- (LPURLConnectionDelegate*) initWithWebView:(UIWebView *)webView;

- (void) loadPageWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)request;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;

@end

@implementation LPURLConnectionDelegate
- (void) loadPageWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)request
{
    _request = [request mutableCopy];
    if(!_data)
    {
        _data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
        [_data retain];
    }
    [_data setLength:0];
    if(_connection)
    {
        [_connection cancel];
        [_connection release];
        _connection = nil;
    }
    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    LPAppDelegate* delegate = [LPAppDelegate getInstance];
    NSURLCredential* credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[delegate getUsername] password:[delegate getPassword] persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //handle connection failed
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Connection did receive response");
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    _mimeType = [httpResponse MIMEType];
    _encoding = [httpResponse textEncodingName];
    //handle status - if the status is 401, the connection is canceled and the user is asked for his new password
}

- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_data appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{    
    [_webView loadData:_data MIMEType:_mimeType textEncodingName:_encoding baseURL:[_request URL]];
}

@end
```

My `UIWebViewDelegate` looks like this:

```
@interface LPWebViewDelegate : NSObject<UIWebViewDelegate>

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;

@end


@implementation LPWebViewDelegate

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //handle success
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
     LPURLConnectionDelegate* connectionDelegate = [[LPURLConnectionDelegate alloc] initWithWebView:webView];
     [connectionDelegate loadPageWithRequest:request];
     return NO;
}

- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //handle fail
}

@end
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is tell the `UIWebView` not to load any page by itself, letting me handle the request to load the page. When the request completes and the user is authenticated, I'm trying to set the data using the `UIWebView::loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseUrl` method.

The problem here is that after setting the `UIWebView`'s data from the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, the `UIWebView` reloads the page set as `baseURL` (at least in the simulator - I haven't tried the code on an actual device just yet).

Does anyone know a way to set data to `UIWebView`s in such way that it doesn't reload the page(*)?

*) I know that I could just let the `UIWebView` load the page after I make the `NSURLConnection` to check for authentication (or in parallel), but I'm trying to avoid requesting the page header twice for each page.

*Note: the code is not complete, I've extracted what I consider to be the most relevant parts for this issue.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003761) class. It essentially a abstract class that allows subclasses to define the URL loading behavior of HTTP schemes

Check this tutorial out [here](http://nshipster.com/nsurlprotocol)